# Blank .tex file after windows blue screen

Tags: errors, texmaker

I was working on a `.tex` file using TeXMaker and suddenly got a blue screen! I restarted my computer and the file I was working with appears blank on TeXmaker, although it is full of `NULL characters` in Notepad++. The size of it is `30 K` which makes me believe my work is still there but somehow hidden.

Have any of you got this before ? Do you know any solution ?
I can send you the file by e-mail if you would need.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format

Comment: `.tex` are ASCII text file fed to LaTeX engine so should be opened normally with Notepad++ even with different `.tex` file input encoding(UTF8 or latin1) _Only_ some characters might show wrong. **In future** Open TeXmaker-->Go to File menu-->`Configure TeXmaker`-->`Editor`--> **Check on** `Backup Documents every 10 min`. so you get `.bak` file created automatically not to lose the data. **Imp**: Remember to save file with `.tex` extension with [latest TeXmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html).

Comment: Perhaps a screenshot will actually be helpful in this scenario.  (Normally such is frowned upon, but I think this is a special case.)  Try opening the file in a binary editor such as [Hexedit](http://www.physics.ohio-state.edu/~prewett/hexedit/) to make sure the 30K is actually 30K of something potentially useful, and not just a [sparse file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file) or something similar.  How full of `NUL` characters is it?

Comment: I see why you've asked this here, but I think this is 'off-topic' for us. The fact that you are dealing with a `.tex` file is really coincidental here: the key thing is recovering the content of a text file after a system crash. What's needed is expertise in file recovery: perhaps SuperUser would be an appropriate place to get ideas.

Comment: I remember a similar problem because a pendrive unmounted by brute force. In this case I was able to recover the file, I think that it was using testdisk in Linux. But this is really off-topic here.

Comment: Did you find a solution? This just happened to me. Bluescreen when compiling. Empty document when opening after restart :/.